# Unable to view who the document is access to in 'Shared With' window

Tags: document-library, sharing

In my claims-based authentication site, when users who have been granted access to the site select 'Shared With' option, only the 'INVITE PEOPLE' link is present. 
[image]

However, accessing the site with my administrator account (Windows Authentication side), I am able to see the rest of the window, including the 'ADVANCED' option and who the document is currently shared with.

The claims based users all have 'Edit' permissions. I'm assuming that since it works on my admin user, it must be a permissions issue. Is 'Edit' not the correct solution? What is the type of permission needed to share?

When I click 'INVITE PEOPLE' with the claims-based users, I get an error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was a permissions issue! I had to either edit an existing permission class, or create a new one to attach to the existing group. See steps below:

1. Go to Site Settings > Site Permissions.
2. Click on 'Permission Levels'.
3. Either edit existing or create new and attach to group with the permission "Site Permissions -> Manage Permissions"